# Traefik routing to wrong location

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, traefik

I have the following URLS:

o.example.com
j.example.com

The idea is, o routes to App1 and j.example.com routes to App2, both have ALB with SSL already setup, so using SSL passthrough

Unfortunately.. when I'm going to o.example.com, its showing j.example.com

My configs in traefik look as following

```
# traefik.yml
api:
  insecure: true

entryPoints:
  web:
    address: :80
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: web-secure
          scheme: https

  web-secure:
    address: :443

providers:
  file:
    filename: "/etc/traefik/config.yml"
    watch: true
```

```
# config.yml
tcp:
  routers:
    oapp:
      rule: "HostSNI(`o.example.com`)"
      service: oservice
      tls:
        passthrough: true

    japp:
      rule: "HostSNI(`j.example.com`)"
      service: jservice
      tls:
        passthrough: true


  services:
    oservice:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: internal-server-app1.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:443

    jservice:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: internal-server.app2.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:443
```

Comment: is routers config missing `entryPoints: -"web-secure:` 
also try setting `priority`

Comment: also set traefik debug logging and can troubleshoot the service registration

Comment: entryPoint didnt help.. and priority isnt available on tcp, I'd like to use http but i cant use ssl passthrough with http routes

Comment: Just a thought.  Is it possible that whatever you are using to query the hostname doesn't support SNI ... can you try using `openssl` `s_client` with `-servername` argument that will do the additional SNI negotiations `openssl s_client -connect o.example.com:443 -servername o.example.com`

Comment: looks like it has something to do with http2.. as it works via curl and in firefox.. doesn't work in chrome

Comment: weird. Chrome supports sending SNI.  Is it possible chrome is using some forward proxy and it's stripping SNI header?